# A question about dimension and connectedness in order topologies

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a totally disconnected topological space T whose topology is the order topology of a linearly ordered set and whose (small inductive) dimension is equal to 1? There exist topological spaces which satisfy all the other conditions, but I do not know of any whose topology is an order topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to [this paper](https://raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/view/56232) zero-dimensionality (in small, or large inductive, or covering definition) is equivalent to being totally disconnected, and all non-such ordered spaces are one-dimensional (in all three definitions). Dimension theory is pretty dull in ordered spaces.

Bernard Brunet, "On the dimension of ordered spaces" (*Collect. Math.*, 48(3):303–314, 1997)

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I’m surprised that the result is so recent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe nobody cared enough, both dimension theory and ordered spaces are somewhat out of fashion? It might have been folklore in some circles, and never written down.

Comment: Or perhaps most of the people who actually were interested in ordered spaces weren’t all that much interested in dimension theory. (Mind you, I could well be over-generalizing from a single instance — me!)

Comment: That $\operatorname{ind}(X) \le 1$ (trivial) and even $\dim(X) \le 1$ (slightly less so) for ordered spaces was well-known, I'm sure, so that sort of trivialises the dimension theory before you even start thinking about it.

Comment: Many thanks for such a complete answer to my question

Comment: Sorry to bring this old post back, but the link is broken: can you write explicitly the name of the reference?

Comment: Found the reference: Brunet, On the dimension of ordered spaces. Collect. Math., 48(3):303–314, 1997

Comment: @Cia: I found an alternative site that provides a PDF of Brunet's paper, thanks to your detective work. Link edited.